# understanding OpenGL ES crash causes and ways to debug one

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

Leaning how to use OpenGL ES under cocos2d-x. 
Help me to understand while the below function crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on noise->visit(); which probably means that my OpenGL state is screwed-up by the time the command is executed.

My method:

```
Sprite* GameLevelLayer::spriteWithColor(Color4F bgColor, float textureWidth, float textureHeight)
{

    // 1: Create new RenderTexture
    auto rt = RenderTexture::create(textureWidth, textureHeight);

    // 2: Call RenderTexture:begin
    rt->beginWithClear(bgColor.r, bgColor.g, bgColor.b, bgColor.a);

    // 3: Draw into the texture
    //// gradient
    gradient_command.init(rt->getGlobalZOrder());
    gradient_command.func = std::bind(&GameLevelLayer::onDrawGradient, this, textureWidth, textureHeight);
    auto renderer = Director::getInstance()->getRenderer();
    renderer->addCommand(&gradient_command);

    //// noise cloud
    BlendFunc blendFunc;
    blendFunc.src = GL_DST_COLOR;
    blendFunc.dst = GL_ZERO;

    auto noise = Sprite::create("Noise.png");
    noise->setBlendFunc(blendFunc);
    noise->setPosition(Vec2(textureWidth / 2, textureHeight / 2));
    // XXX
    noise->visit();

    // 4: Call RenderTexture:end
    rt->end();

    // 5: Create a new Sprite from the texture
    return Sprite::createWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
}
```

and the gradient:

```
void GameLevelLayer::onDrawGradient(float textureWidth, float textureHeight)
{
    setGLProgram(ShaderCache::getInstance()->getGLProgram(GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_COLOR));
    getGLProgram()->use();
    getGLProgram()->setUniformsForBuiltins();

    float gradientAlpha = 0.8f;

    std::vector<Vec2> vertices;
    std::vector<Color4F> colors;

    vertices.push_back(Vec2(0, 0));
    colors.push_back(Color4F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ));

    vertices.push_back(Vec2(textureWidth, 0));
    colors.push_back(Color4F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ));

    vertices.push_back(Vec2(0, textureHeight));
    colors.push_back(Color4F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, gradientAlpha ));

    vertices.push_back(Vec2(textureWidth, textureHeight));
    colors.push_back(Color4F(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, gradientAlpha ));

    GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION | GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_COLOR);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices.data());
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors.data());
    glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)vertices.size());
}
```

Is this because I am using parameters of a wrong size, somewhere? How does one go about debugging something like this?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems working fine without any problem. are you running the code in simulator? I am using the Cocos2dx v3.6 btw.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am running it in Simulator and the code crashes. Should I try on the device?

Comment: It is crashes on the device, as well. Good suggestion, though. Thank you. I am running cocos2d-x 3.7.

Comment: which OS you using btw?

Comment: I am running iOS 7.0 on my development iPhone, and XCode 6.x with 8.1 for my simulator. My guess is that something is messed-up with my OpenGL ES state. I just have no clue to even go about debugging it. Possibly, "my" code works for you, because the stack is being screwed elsewhere...

Comment: So weird. I am sure you probably know all these, but you definitely using breakpoints right! and sometimes when I use xcode in debug mode all code seems to work fine when I step through break points. At such times I also use CClog inside the methods that are called before the crash. If your definetly sure that the crash is inside the Node::visit method then you might want to add some breakpoints and CCLogs in there too. Please also make sure that there is no errors showing in console.Sometimes if there is an issue with your  Opengl call you will get a descriptive error message.

Comment: Definitely true. I was just wondering whether there are/were OpenGL ES debugging tools simple enough for someone who only knows OpenGL very little. :) The crash is inside Camera::getViewMatrix() on Mat4 viewInv(getNodeToWorldTransform());

Comment: You can capture the [OpenGL ES frames](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/debugging_opengl_es_frame.html) in Xcode but not sure if your issue is with OpenGL calls though. 

GetNodeToWorldTransform is a member of a node class. It returns inverse matrix that used for transforming  from local to  world coordinate system.

Method loops through all parents of a node you calling frm, I think one of the parent node is somehow deleted in your code? CCLog or break point the for loop inside the GetNodeToWorldTransform which may let you find the offending parent.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. Perhaps, I forgot to call retain somewhere. Good looking out. Hope to continue.